# How to Update Products Status Directly from Database

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am using Magento version 1.9.2.
I have 6000 disabled products with 0 quantity and stock status Out of stock that's why products are not displaying on front end.

I want to update the products directly from database i made changes

```
cataloginventory_stock_item
qty=12
is_in_stock=1
manage_stock=1

cataloginventory_stock_status
stock_status=1 
qty=12

catalog_product_entity_int
value=1 where attribute_id=96
```

after doing these changes flush the cache but still no product is displaying on front end but at back end all products have 12 qty in stock and status is enabled.

here i am confuse that if i select a product and just click save button without making any change then product displayed on front end. that means something is missing that should need to be update in database. what is that? i request you all kindly help me in it.

Comment: you should try to reindex

Comment: Still some products are not showing up on front end

Answer (score 0):

$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
foreach($products as $product)
{
        $prd=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getId());
        $prd->save();
}

you use this script that will save all product. and all product will display in frontend side.